# No creeping doubts! No feeling persecuted

Tags: sentence-meaning

The context is from the Inception movie:

> Ariadne and Cobb enter Mal and Cobb's home]
>
> Dom Cobb: An idea is like
>   a virus, resiliant, highly contagious and the smallest seed of an idea
>   can grow. It can grow to define or destroy you. [they find Mal sitting
>   in their kitchen table]
>
> Mal: A smallest idea such as 'your world is
>   not real'. Simple little thought that changes everything. You're so
>   certain of your world, of what's real. Do you think he is? Or do you
>   think he's as lost as I was?
>
> Dom Cobb: I know what's real, Mal.
>
> Mal:*No creeping doubts? Not feeling persecuted,* Dom? Chased around the
>   globe by annonymous corporations and police forces, the way the
>   projections persecute the dreamer? Admit it, you don't believe in one
>   reality anymore. So choose, choose to be here, choose me.

Could you explain what she was trying to say by these two sentences?

Comment: *No evidence of prior research?* What exactly is so hard to understand about such usages? Not the definitions of the six italicised words themselves, surely?

Comment: I can't explain anything about that movie. I didn't understand it and it made me nauseous. Anyway, what specific issue(s) regarding the two phrases are giving you trouble? Both have the -ing form, so perhaps you are asking about that? Your answer is close to getting put on hold because we need more information from you.

Comment: @CarSmack I was totally confused by the phrase no creeping doubts. I found that _to creep_ generally means to move slowly and carefully. How could it ever be connected with the noun _dount_?  Might she mean the doubts which were appeared slowly, gradually in the Cobb's head?

Comment: Yes Dmitry, that is what it means, *creeping doubts* are doubts that form and grow slowly. They may be too small to perceive at first, but they keep creeping along until you are aware you have them.

Comment: @CarSmack Thank you. It's clear now. Couldn't you make a clarification about _no feeling persecuted_? As dictionaries say _to persecute someone_ means to continually come after them in order to catch or even kill them. So she asked about did Cobb feel that anonymous corporation and police forces try  to catch him. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly. So they both use the present participle, creeping, feeling...

Answer (score 1):

"No creeping doubts?" Implies a condition where one may have an additional opinion or thought which is kept just out of light. It asks if there is another possibility in one's mind that has yet to be discounted.

A similar statement might be: "No nagging doubts?"

The second sentence refers both to the legal forces pursuing his character in the real world because he is a criminal, and those components of his psyche pursuing him during the semi-conscious/dreamlike state because his projection is supplanting the true nature of the psyche's existence/reality.

Both sentences play on the concept of expelling that which is corrupt, seditious or untrue to the core of the self. She's asking if he truly knows where he is in their relationship.